# How to detect what window/control is at a specific point onscreen?

Tags: winapi, gdi

Is there a Win32 API call to determine what window and/or control is visible at a certain coordinates and/or under the mouse?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`GetWindowFromPoint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633558(v=vs.85).aspx). It will return the window handle so you can than use [`GetClassName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633582(v=vs.85).aspx) function to see which control it is.

here is an example:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/112649

Comment: Amazing. I've been beating my head against the wall for a while trying to find this. Thanks! :D

Answer (score 1):

Use the **WindowFromPoint**, **ChildWindowFromPoint** or **ChildWindowFromPointEx** Win32 functions.