# How to get window class by HWND?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, wtl

I need to check window class under cursor.
How can I get window class by `HWND`?

Answer (score 3):

If you have the handle to the window you need the class from just use [GetClassName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633582%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

[`ChildWindowFromPoint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632676%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and friends - make sure to read carefully on disabled/invisible windows.

See: [How to detect what window/control is at a specific point onscreen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1236412/how-to-detect-what-window-control-is-at-a-specific-point-onscreen)